# get two controls to be right next to each other

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I want this label and its check box to be right next to each other. However, no matter how I try, I cannot get it to be.  I have tried putting them in the same div. I have tried float, text-align, and a combination of the two.  What do I need to do? right now there is too much which space inbetween them.

```
<div class="col-md-1" style="text-align: right">
         @Html.Label("Public", new { @class = "control-label" })
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
         @Html.CheckBox("PublicNote", new { @class = "chk=style", @checked = "checked" })
</div>
```

Should this be done in css or in the view? I only need to do it in this one case.

Answer (score 1):

Put `Label` and `Checkbox` in the same `div` and add `display:inline-block` to `control-label` class.

Comment: That went below it, not next to it.

Comment: what is "that" and what is "it"?

Comment: The example you gave me made the checkbox go below the label.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="block">
    <label>Label with more text</label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.block label { display: inline-block; width: 140px; text-align: right; }
```

**OR**

```
<div> <label><input type="checkbox"/> Inline Form </label> </div>
```

Comment: That made it worse, not better